# How to make owl-carousel with rotating cursor work in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, owl-carousel

I have been trying to make this owl-carousel by John Higgins (http://jonhiggins.co.uk/words/animated-rotating-cursor-over-carousel/) work with bootstrap.

This theme makes the cursor act like 'prev' and 'next' buttons when hovering the carousel image. But it seem that when I put html into a responsive container of bootstrap it somehow messes with the cursor.

When the browser width is expanded you will notice that the arrow doesn't switch from right to left. Please have a look at the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ftpptf/c6nw8yzt/

```
/* BEGIN Cursor*/
.cursor {
display: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
width:33px;
height:54px;
margin-top: 60px;
margin-left: 33px;
pointer-events: none;
&.isVisible {
    display: block;
}
}
.js--visible {
display: block;
 }
.cursor__icon {
width:32px;
height:32px;
background-image:               url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAw  MC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDMyIDMyIiBpZD0ic3ZnIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNmZmYiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iNCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbWl0ZXJsa    W1pdD0iMTAiIGQ9Ik0yNC4xIDMwTDcuOSAxNiAyNC4xIDIiPjwvcGF0aD48L3N2Zz4=');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-out;
transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
}
.carousel.offScreen .cursor {
display: none;
}
.carousel.right .cursor__icon {
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
/* END Cursor*/
```

I have set .cursor .cursor__icon position = absolute which seemed to help but it still acts weird.

I have tried loads of different settings but without any good results!

Any help will be highly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad the Codepen example is of use to you.

It looks like the issue is that your carousel's left edge isn't at 0px (far left of the window),  it's halfway across the screen. My example didn't account for this scenario as the carousel filled the viewport horizontally.

Hopefully this fiddle resolves that: https://jsfiddle.net/jonjhiggins/z915kbe3/

Changes made were:

1. CSS: making the carousel and images 100% width instead of 800px (so that it will responsively fill the width of whatever you set it's parent to)

   ```
   .carousel {
       width: 100%;
       cursor: none;
   }
   .carousel img {
       width:100%;
   }
   ```
2. JS: changing initLayout to account for when the carousel isn't on far left of screen

   ```
   var _initLayout = function () {
       left = $element.offset().left;
       right = left + ($element.width() / 2);
   };
   ```
3. JS: add resize event to re-calculate the left/right positions when the window is resized or device is rotated

   ```
   var _initEvents = function () {
       $element.on('mousemove', _mousemove)
           .on('click', _click);
       $(window).on('resize', _initLayout);
   };
   ```

Comment: Jon you are the man - in danish "dagens mand i skysovs"!! Thanks

Comment: No problem :) if it answers your question, please "mark as answered" (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)